# Unknown user or entry in MYSQL user list - 20.04 - fresh install

Tags: server, 20.04, mysql, security

The story is pretty simple. I deployed two Ubuntu 20.04 VMs in the cloud. I installed a generic LAMP stack on both, nothing fancy. When I ran MySQL and checked users, **it's showing a random line there**. What random line? Well, let me show you. Even the formatting is broken compared to a normal user. If I check it on a production server of mine, all the other entries show up totally fine.

`SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;`

```
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                                                  | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
 DD6EG\  ;^LH0^]8^S3saBHoechBdF2mY... | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *RANDOMVALUES                                                          | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | OK                                                                     | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
| mysql.session    | OK                                                                     | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | OK                                                                     | caching_sha2_password | localhost |
| root             | *RANDOMVALUES                                                          | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

I verified this by installing Ubuntu 20.04 in a local VirtualBox. As soon as I install mysql-server, it shows this random entry. I say random because it's not the same as on my server. Anyone has any clue what that is? What does it do?

Comment: It's a bug, for sure. The users that ought to be present in a new MySQL installation are all the other ones. So perhaps you can just delete this row.

Comment: @Jos The interesting bit is that I have now reinstalled the VM after rollback and installed `ubuntu-desktop` meta package, then installed mysql-server from the GUI. Then, I did not have this weird line. It's like there is an authentication string, but the user is missing? I tried dumping every line with `SELECT * from mysql.user` with `INTO` a file, but I still cannot decypher what the heck is this extra line that randomly gets added. At first I thought server got compromised but this must be something else.